# C# EndsWith more than one value

Tags: c#

How can i get more values in a EndsWith?

For example

```
if(textbox1.Text.EndsWith("hotmail.com" && "anothermail.com"){

}
```

What to do?

Comment: Break it up into two separate calls.

Comment: **.EndsWith("mail.com")**?

Comment: I assume `&&` is a typo because I read that in my head as `ends with "hotmail.com" and "anothermail.com"`

Answer (score 5):

You can create an extension method:

```
public static bool EndsWithAny(this string str, params string[] search)
{
    return search.Any(s => str.EndsWith(s));
}

//Call
bool found = str.EndsWithAny("hotmail.com", "anothermail.com");
```

Comment: Shorter: `search.Any(str.EndsWith)`

Comment: True, but I prefer writing the lambda expression as it is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the results where the value ends with one string, or ends with the other string, then combine the two checks with a logical or:

```
if(textbox1.Text.EndsWith("hotmail.com") || textbox1.Text.EndsWith("anothermail.com")) { ... }
```

Comment: In case the OP has more than 2 strings to check, this is also possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796891/string-endswith

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] ends = new string[] { "hotmail.com" , "anothermail.com" };
string text = "example.hotmail.com2";
bool endsWith = ends.Any(e => text.EndsWith(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a collection and `Any`+`EndsWith`:

```
var mails = new[] { "hotmail.com", "anothermail.com" };
bool endsWithAny= mails.Any(textbox1.Text.EndsWith);
```